# LaTeX cmd Error: Command '\unit' already defined. }

Tags: pdftex, luatex, siunitx

I'm facing an issue while compiling my LaTeX document on my system. The error message I receive is:

```
LaTeX cmd Error: Command '\unit' already defined. }
```

However, the exact same file compiles without any issues on a different system. Any assistance or insights into resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Sadly (but probably unsurprisingly) my crystal ball is very cloudy today; actually, my crystal ball is very cloudy *every day*. To give readers of your posting a chance to start a diagnosis what may be going on, do please edit it to provide actionable information regarding "my [TeX] system", "a different [TeX] system" -- and when these systems were last updated. Please also show not only an error message but also the code that generates the error message, along with the lines immediately before and after the problem line of code.

Comment: Welcome! Rephrasing Mico, could you please edit your question to include the code needed to reproduce the error? It'd also be helpful if you could include the version of your TeX installation(s).

Answer (score 2):

Without an example i cannot be sure, but it is likely that one system has `siunitx` v3 and the other had `siunitx` v2, and your source is alos loading something like the `units` package.

In v2 of `siunitx`, the command to typeset units was called `\si`, and you could load the `units` package at the same time. That was never a great command name, and as `units` has been superseded for >15 years, it felt that I could use the same command name on the grounds that almost no-one would be using both packages.

If we stick to `\si`, move `\unit` out of the way and prevent an error, you can still use both:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\let\unit\undefined
\usepackage{units}
\expandafter\let\csname ver@units.sty\endcsname\relax
\begin{document}

\si{\metre} and \unit{m}

\end{document}
```

though I don't recommend this.