# command \unit already defined

Tags: pstricks

The sequence

```
\documentclass{amsbook} 
\usepackage{pst-eucl} 
\usepackage{prerex}    
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

generates `command \unit already defined' error.  Either of the two packages by itself is no problem.  This error message did not arise with MikTex 2.9 even with maximal updates.
However, using MikTex 23.10 causes this problem to arise, it seems.

In the end I was able to eliminate the problem using the following.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\savesymbol{unit}
\usepackage{prerex}
\restoresymbol{PREREX}{unit}
\begin{document}
\begin{chart}
\end{chart}
\end{document}
```

This got me past the preamble.  However, the first invocation of prerex (\begin{chart}) raised the new error `!missing number, treated as zero...\xparse not expandable ....1.8 \begin{chart}'.  Thanks.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697499/latex-cmd-error-command-unit-already-defined/697502#697502

Comment: DavidCarlisle's link suggests to just have `\let\unit\undefined` between the two `\usepackage`.  That seems to work, even with the `{chart}`.  Have you tried that instead of `savesymbol`?

Comment: Yes, \let\unit\undefined worked.  Thanks to you (and to David Carlisle).

Answer (score 3):

The `prerex` package does

```
\newlength{\unit}
```

which is the cause of the error, together with the fact that `pst-eucl` loads many `pstricks` related subpackages among which `pst-calculate` which loads `siunitx` and this one defines `\unit`.

I believe that `\unit` as the name for the adjustable parameter in `prerex` is not a good choice.

Since `prerex` also loads `hyperref` (I don't really know why), it should be loaded as late as possible and it might check for `\unit` being defined, in this case offering a different name. The code might be

```
\@ifundefined{unit}{%
  \newlength{\unit}%
  \let\prerex@unit\unit
}{%
  \newlength{\prerexunit}%
  \let\prerex@unit\prerexunit
  \PackageWarning{prerex}{\protect\unit already defined, use \protect\prerexunit instead}
}
```

changing all the other appearances of `\unit` in the package code with `\prerex@unit`. This way, user code that uses `prerex` without conflicts would work the same as before. The warning will tell the user what to do. Of course this is a job for the package maintainer.

For the time being, do `\let\unit\relax` before `\usepackage{prerex}` and use `\si` if you need the `\unit` command from `siunitx`.